# Android: manipulate a variable's value inside Service methods and get from different Activities

Tags: android, variables, binding, service, android-activity

I implemented Service for listening user location:

```
public class ListenLocationService extends Service {
    private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();

public interface ILocationService {      
      public void StartListenLocation();
      public Location getUserLocation();
    }

public class LocalBinder extends Binder implements ILocationService{
    LocationManager locationManager;
    LocationListener locationListener;
    Location userLocation = null;

    public void StartListenLocation()
    {   
        locationManager = (LocationManager)ListenLocationService.this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationListener = new LocationListener() {

            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

            }       

            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

            }

            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

            }

            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {                      
                userLocation = location;    
                Log.d("Service", "Location changed at: "+userLocation.toString());
            }
        };
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 
                0, 0, locationListener);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 
                0, 0, locationListener);        
    }

    public Location getUserLocation(){
        Log.d("Service", "return location: "+userLocation.toString());
        return userLocation;
    }

    public void onPause() {
        //super.onPause();
        locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);
    }

    public void onResume() {
        //super.onResume();
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 
                0, 0, locationListener);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 
                0, 0, locationListener);
    }
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return mBinder;
}
```

}

There's a variable `Location userLocation` in `LocalBinder` class.
I putted `Log.d` in `onLocationChanged` function, so I saw that userLocation value is ok.

In first Activity I bind it with my Service and call `StartListenLocation` method:

```
private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className,
                IBinder service) {
            mService = (ILocationService) service; 
            mService.StartListenLocation();    
        }

        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0) {
        }
    };

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
...
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ListenLocationService.class);
        bindService(intent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
...
}
```

In the second Activity I also make a bind with Service and call `getUserLocation()` method:

```
private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className,
                IBinder service) {
            mService = (ILocationService) service; 
            Location userLocation = mService.getUserLocation();
            showUserLocation(userLocation);  
        }

        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0) {
        }
    };
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
...
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ListenLocationService.class);
        bindService(intent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
...
}
```

However, here `userLocation` variable is null in spite of not null value in output from method call from first Activity.

I need to start Service from my first Activity and begin updating `userLocation` from now and during all other Activities work.

In next Activity I'm trying to get `userLocation` but I'm getting null. Why it happens?

Why I can't manipulate a variable inside Service's methods and get it where I need?

Comment: When the second Activity binds to the service, is the first Activity still active? or has it finished()?

Comment: Remove private from IBinder mBinder

Comment: @DavidWasser first Activity is stopped when second is active

Comment: @jjNford it didn't solve the problem

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean the first Activity is stopped? Have you called finish() on it?

Comment: no, I only called startActivity(secondActivity);

Comment: You have debug logging in `getUserLocation()` in the service. Do you see this output in the logcat? Does it contain the correct location? My thought was that the service is shutting down between the bindService() calls in the first Activity and the second, but that's just a guess.

Comment: `userLocation` variable inside `getUserLocation()` is null. Service doesn't shut down, because I don't unbind it anywhere and I see GPS icon at device all time (it means that service continue to listen location)

Comment: Try moving Location userLocation = null; declaration out form the inner LocalBinder class, and declare it in ListenLocationService class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve required result, `Location userLocation` declaration should be moved to `ListenLocationService` class.

To set new value to `userLocation`, use this code: `userLocation.set(location);`

because `userLocation = new Location(location);` cause *remove final modifier* error even if there's no final modifier.