# Using a variable in another class

Tags: java, android, variables, latitude-longitude

referring to the code below.. I got a class LocationService and have a variable latitude in it. I want use that variable in another class Post. How do I do that.
Basically I want get the latitude and longitude which i get from there in the other class also.. As I want to post it on the server.
So how do i do that.

LocationService.java

```
public class LocationService extends Service{

Context context;
WakeLock wl;


@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}


public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager)getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "lock");
    wl.acquire();
    context = this;
    final String who = intent.getStringExtra("who");
    final LocationManager locMan = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    final LocationListener listener = new LocationListener(){

        // start location changed

        public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
            double latitude = loc.getLatitude();
            double longitude = loc.getLongitude();
                                    ......
                                    ......
                                    }
Post.java

public class Post extends LocationService {
```

}

**EDITED**
Post.java

```
public class Post extends LocationService {{

super.latitude = loc.getLatitude();


 }
 }
```

Will this get me the latitude from LocationService class to Post class..?

Comment: how do you use the `Post` class? Is it another different Service?

Comment: yah!! a different service.. I want to get the latitudes and longitudes from class LocationService to the class Post and then in class will help me post the latitudes and longitudes on a server

Comment: Take `latitude` and `longitude` variables outside the `LocationListener` and make them the direct members of `LocationService` class. That is, put them where you've declared `context` and `wl`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your OOPS Concepts are not Clear. Go [HERE](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/index.html)

You will have to make those variables Public as you want them to be used in other Classes and declare it where `Context` is declared.
Then you can make an object of the class and use it. Get the Fundamentals Clear.

Comment: @RadhaKumar: write  `double latitude;` below context declaration part

Comment: after that... the value of the latitude and longitude can be used in the Post class...?

Comment: Yes make object of that class `LocationService ls;` and call it by ls.latitude;

Answer (score 1):

Define some protected variables in LocationService then Post can see them. Or write getter methods in LocationService and call them from Post  with super.getLat

Answer (score 0):

I had a same problem, see question and answer here: [Android: pass parameter to Service from Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9954878/android-pass-parameter-to-service-from-activity)

In few words, you need to create an interface that declare all method signature that you want to call from a `Activity`, implement its methods in your `LocalBinder` and then reference to this interface from your `Activity`.

Comment: Please have a look to my edited part... will that get me the values of latitude and longitude.