# How to pass Object of Service to MyActivity?

Tags: java, android, sockets, object, android-service-binding

**First of all: I am bigger in Android programming**

I have created simple TCP Socket using Service.

The client connects to server when the button in `MainActivity` is triggered.

Now i want to create `PrintWriter` object in `MainActivity` using `Socket` object of Service.

I got to know it is possible to pass objects from `Service` to `Activity` using JSON.

I searched over Internet but couldn't get an idea how I can pass it.

Please give me simple code example to pass the object.

MyService.java

```
public class MyService extends Service{
public static Socket clientsocket;
public static PrintWriter printer;
SendMessage sender;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
Toast.makeText(this, "Created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
super.onCreate();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
Toast.makeText(this, "Stoped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
if(clientsocket!=null){
        try{
        clientsocket.close(); 
        Toast.makeText(this, "Socket Closed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
  }

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Running", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    SendMessage sender=new SendMessage();
    sender.execute();
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return null;
}

class SendMessage extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            clientsocket = new Socket("192.168.237.1", 6666);
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        if(clientsocket!=null){
            Toast.makeText(MyService.this, "Connected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(MyService.this, "Lost Connection", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }

   }}
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}

public void start(View v){
    startService(new Intent(this,MyService.class));
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
     getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
     return true;
}

class PrintMessage extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        return null;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    stopService(new Intent(this,MyService.class));
    super.onDestroy();
}}
```

**Now I need a clear & complete code for both MyService.java (how to pass object I.e. in this case  `Socket` object `clientsocket` )and MainActivity.java (how to retreive passed object I.e. `clientsocket` and use it to create `PrintWriter` object)**

Comment: as it is json, u can broadcast an intent with a simple extra string. Also, if you bind the activity, you can return an interface method 'sendData(String)' so whatever the client can send in json

Comment: If it is possible can u give me simple code !

Comment: intents: http://android-coding.blogspot.com.es/2011/11/pass-data-from-service-to-activity.html

Comment: binder: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9954878/android-pass-parameter-to-service-from-activity

Comment: all sort of: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html

Comment: Let me try. Keep rocking

Answer (score 0):

Please consider using an event bus library, like greenrobot EventBus :-) Those work wonders when it comes to passing data between the elements of the app and are pretty safe to use.

Comment: I want to pass the socket object to activity here... not the data. I want tobuse it to create `PrintWriter` object using it in Activity

Answer (score 0):

I personally would use the following solution [How to send event from Service to Activity with Otto event bus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15431768/how-to-send-event-from-service-to-activity-with-otto-event-bus) with **Otto** Event Bus, and just send an instance of the class with the data in it.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity
{

    @Override
    protected void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        SingletonBus.INSTANCE.getBus().register(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause()
    {
        SingletonBus.INSTANCE.getBus().unregister(this);
        super.onPause();
    }
    ...
}
```

And

```
// you might need to change this as linked in the above link: 
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15431768/how-to-send-event-from-service-to-activity-with-otto-event-bus
public enum SingletonBus
{
    INSTANCE;

    private Bus bus;

    private SingletonBus()
    {
        this.bus = new Bus(ThreadEnforcer.ANY);
    }

    public Bus getBus()
    {
        return bus;
    }
}
```

and

```
public class MyEvent
{
    private Data data;

    public MyEvent(Data data)
    {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public Data getData()
    {
        return data;
    }
}
```

and

```
SingletonBus.INSTANCE.getBus().post(new MyEvent(data));
```

Comment: This is a new concept for me... let me study it. Btw keep rocking